# opengl es 2.0 drawing imprecision

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

Im having a weird issue in opengl, it goes like this: im designing a 2d engine, so far i coded the routines that let's you draw sprites, rectangle, boxes, translate and scale them... however when i run a small demo of my engine i notice when scaling gradually rectangles in an animation (drawn using 4 vertices and GL_LINE_LOOP), the rectangle edeges seems to bounce between the two neighboring pixels.
I can't determine the source of the problem or even formulate a proper search query in google, if someone can shed some light on this matter. If my question is not understood please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Building a 2D library on OpenGL ES is going to be problematic for several reasons.  First of all, the Khronos specifications state that it is not intended to produce "pixel perfect" rendering. Every OpenGL ES renderer is allowed some variation in rendered results. This is because the actual rendering is implemented in hardware and floating point rounding can be a little different from platform to platform.  Even the shader compilers are completely different from one GPU to the next.

Another issue is that most of the GPUs on mobile devices today are tile-based deferred renderers, and they do not typically support partial screen rendering.  In other words, every screen update requires replacing the entire frame.